# He is a straight man = he is honest, keeps his words (possible usage?)

Tags: word-usage

Checked the dictionaries, so one of the meanings of *straight* is *honest*, but can we use it for a man/woman as in my  question above?

Comment: Aside: the phrase you used should be "keeps his word" (singular). Similar usage: "my word is my bond" and "take my word for it."

Answer (score 3):

You *can* use **straight** like that, but [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/straight) gives more meanings, so it might be unclear exactly what you mean.

- Honest
- Direct
- Heterosexual
- Uncomplicated

Also a "straight man" can be one half of a comedy double act.

So it might be better to choose a synonym which expresses what you mean (unless that can be inferred from the context).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should use more advanced vocabulary to make it more flexible. 
 
Suggested substituents (with links to Cambridge Dictionary provided):

1. *[open-minded](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/open-minded)* - ready to sth new and interesting
2. *[trustworthy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trustworthy)* -, to my mind, the best one.
3. *[candid](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/candid)* - implying readiness to discuss sth unpleasant

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative that avoids the ambiguity of "straight man" is

> He's a straight shooter.

This indicates that he's honest and direct.